# NavigationController, Why will it not work the way i want it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm doing the fourth assignment on the Stanford Iphone Dev Course.

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    ListViewController *listview = [[ListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ListView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:listview animated:NO];
    [listview release];
}
```

So, i'm trying to get my get my listview inside of the navigationcontrollers view. but the thing that happens is that the listview gets a new view with a "back to rootcontroller" button in the navigation bar. and when i click it i get back to the navigationcontroller view that is empty.

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want your ListViewController to be rootViewController, you should do smth like this

> ```
> [navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:listView] animated:YES];
> ```

instead of `pushViewController`. pushViewController just add your listView to the top of the controller's stack. initial viewController stays with an empty view.

Comment: Thats what im trying to do, how do i add it to the stack?

Answer (score 0):

You can also assign your ListViewController as the root view controller for your navigation controller during instantiation:

```
[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootController:listview ]
```